# Is it possible to validate google recapctha response using only server side Javascript

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have a proprietary button (not an HTML input) that has fires of serverside JS scripts using an onclick event. I am trying to implement a Google Recaptcha v2 to prevent some spamming, the button has options to add html or client side jS/JQuery as well and I have added this.

```
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {


   var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if(v.length == 0)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="You can't leave Captcha Code empty";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="Captcha completed";
        return true; 
    }
});
```

I have successfully got the recaptcha working and it fires an alert **first** time if not checked,  but if all other form validations are ok,  but the second time it still submits.
I would like to somehow get the Recaptcha response in the serverside submit script,  but struggling to find the right method... is it even possible 
Happy to try any other method if someone has an option?